# Microsoft office 2010 template changes and updating the documents that were created using the template

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, templates

We have letterhead that was created and saved as a template. We have other documents that were created using the template. Occasionally the letterhead needs updates, new logo, new numbers, etc.
How can I ensure all the documents that were created using this template will be updated to reflect the changes made?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New users sometimes fail to include what they have attempted or researched before posting a question. It is not big deal, just [edit] your question to include more details about what you have done so far. We will try to help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word doesn't have this feature.

Templates and Documents created from templates are not linked and independent files.

I agree this would be a nice feature but at this moment it doesn't exist